# Android Hybrid App Keyboard/Dropdown popup resize issue for offscreen navigation

Tags: android, css, cordova

Below is my offscreen navigation menu

[image]

Whenever i open a keyboard or dropdown then after the offscreen menu looks like this

[image]

There is a small gap on the left side that is appearing only after the popup occurs (indicated in red box). The menu is moving more far from the border.

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem. This only occurs in Android devices. IOS is working fine.

Im using pushy css3 menu for the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

What happens on Android when the keyboard is opened, is that the viewport of the webpage gets resized. The actually viewport is changed and the website/webapp does not know it is because of the keyboard. This resize can trigger alternative CSS code for smaller views (think about responsive layout here). At least, that was my issue with jQuery Mobile.